# Xamarin Forms Listview's Entry conflict with custom picker

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a really strange problem is happening with my application, I have a custom picker with an image in the header of a listview, the XAML and the C# code:

```
<controls:CustomPicker Image="arrow" x:Name="filter1" SelectedIndexChanged="filter1_SelectedIndexChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="Black" Title="Category">
                                <controls:CustomPicker.Margin>
                                    <OnIdiom Phone="8,8,8,8" Tablet="12,12,12,12"/>
                                </controls:CustomPicker.Margin>
                                <controls:CustomPicker.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom Phone="16" Tablet="24"/>
                                </controls:CustomPicker.FontSize>
                            </controls:CustomPicker>

 public async void filter1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            index = 0;
            var selected = filter1.Items[filter1.SelectedIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                if (mylist[i].description == selected && selected != null && selected != "")
                {
                    await GetItemsCategorized(mylist[i].code, index, searching.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

and the listview that has an entry in the viewcell, the XAML and the C# code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                    <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"  WidthRequest="40">
                                                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                                                            <controls:NumericValidationBehavior/>
                                                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                                                    </Entry>
                                                </StackLayout> 




  private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = sender as Entry;
        var product = entry.BindingContext as Sales_Order_Items;
        if (e.NewTextValue != null && e.NewTextValue != "" && !e.NewTextValue.Contains("-") && !e.NewTextValue.Contains("."))
            product.requested_quantity = int.Parse(e.NewTextValue.ToString());
        else
            product.requested_quantity = 0;
    }
```

The thing is on android when the listview is displayed on Android when I focus on the entry on every viewcell the picker is enabled with the keyboard and the keyboard disappear!!!! while on iOS it works fine:

[focusing on entry-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh2LK.png)

[focused on entry-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQLhN.png)

[focused on entry-ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goR3p.png)

Any idea why this is happening?!!

Answer (score 0):

The custom picker was placed in the header of the listview, I placed it outside the listview the application is working fine now!!